# Angular js display gmail like overlapping email threads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to build something like this (similar to gmail email thread):

```
 |--------------------------|
 |  first message (clipped) |
 |--------------------------|
 |--------------------------|
 |======= 4 messages  ======| 
 |--------------------------|
 |--------------------------|
 | 2nd last msg (clipped)   |
 |--------------------------|
 | Hello there,             |
 | this is my last message  |
 | complete text is         |
 | displayed                |
 |--------------------------|
```

You have multiple messages, all are initially collapsed and user can only see last message, with some part of 1st and 2nd last message. When user clicks on the center part of the collapsed part, all the messages are expanded.

Is there a angular custom directive that provides something similar or something open source I could use that will provide expand/collapse option. I am trying to avoid writing this from scratch.

I had a look at the bootstrap accordion, but it will expand/collapse entire message thread.

Any guidance/help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some CSS also you can achieve the desired result:

```
<div class="inbox">
    <div class="message">
      Message 1
     </div>
     <div class="message">
      Message 2
     </div>
     <div class="message">
      Message 3
     </div>
     <div class="message">
      Message 4
     </div> <div class="message">
      Message 5
     </div> <div class="message">
      Message 6
     </div> <div class="message">
      Message 7 - last message
     </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message {
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.message:first-child {
    height: 100px;   
}

.message:last-child {
    height: auto;    
}
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/2z34sfk5/1/)**

Comment: You could use overflow: hidden on .message for the text doesn't overlap next texts

Answer (score 1):

You could use two things: To use a css to cut on line size, or use a angular filter to limit the max chars.

I made a jsbin code to show both:

http://jsbin.com/ceduji/2/edit?html,css,js,output

using style:

```
li { overflow: hidden; height: 20px; }
```

using filter:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in list">
    <li>{{ item | limitTo: 50 }}</li>
</ul>
```